# How do I group by with name, preserve keys and names using itertools?

Tags: python, python-itertools, itertools-groupby

I am working with a data set that is a simple SQL Query that fetches the desired rows.

```
[(2, 5, 'JOHN K', 'YAHOO'), (2, 6, 'AARON M', 'YAHOO'), (2, 7, 'NICK C', 'YAHOO'), (1, 2, 'CELESTE G', 'GOOGLE'), (1, 3, 'RICH M', 'GOOGLE'), (1, 4, 'SANDEEP C', 'GOOGLE')]
```

What I have so far that yields the grouping without keys -

```
import itertools
import operator


def accumulate(rows):
    # itemgetter fetches and groups them by company name(3)
    it = itertools.groupby(rows, operator.itemgetter(3))
    k = {}
    for key, subiter in it:
        k[key] = ';'.join(item[2] for item in subiter)
    return k


if __name__ == '__main__':

    rows = [(2, 5, 'JOHN K', 'YAHOO'), (2, 6, 'AARON M', 'YAHOO'), (2, 7, 'NICK C', 'YAHOO'), (1, 2, 'CELESTE G', 'GOOGLE'), (1, 3, 'RICH M', 'GOOGLE'), (1, 4, 'SANDEEP C', 'GOOGLE')] 
    groupedby = (accumulate(rows))

    print(groupedby)
```

Output -

```
{'YAHOO': 'JOHN K;AARON M;NICK C', 'GOOGLE': 'CELESTE G;RICH M;SANDEEP C'}
```

Desired Output preserve the keys and still do the grouping -

```
{('YAHOO,2'): '(JOHN K,5);(AARON M,6);(NICK C,7)', ('GOOGLE,1'): '(CELESTE G,2);(RICH M,3);(SANDEEP C,4)'}
```

I am open to some other data structure that is not comma separated, using pipes or may be a tuple.

```
for key, subiter in it:
    k[key, ] = ';'.join(item[2] for item in subiter)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# 1
ans = {}
for a, b, c, d in arr:
    ans.setdefault("".join(["(", ",".join([d, str(a)]), ")"]), []).\
        append("".join(["(", ",".join([c, str(b)]), ")"]))
{k: ";".join(v) for k, v in ans.items()}
# {'(YAHOO,2)': '(JOHN K,5);(AARON M,6);(NICK C,7)',
#  '(GOOGLE,1)': '(CELESTE G,2);(RICH M,3);(SANDEEP C,4)'}
```

```
# 2
ans = {}
for el in arr:
    a, b, c, d = el
    key = "".join(["(", ",".join([d, str(a)]), ")"])
    val = "".join(["(", ",".join([c, str(b)]), ")"])
    if ans.get(key) is None:
        ans[key] = [val]
    else:
        ans[key].append(val)

for k, v in ans.items():
    ans[k] = ";".join(v)

ans
# {'(YAHOO,2)': '(JOHN K,5);(AARON M,6);(NICK C,7)',
#   '(GOOGLE,1)': '(CELESTE G,2);(RICH M,3);(SANDEEP C,4)'}​
```

```
# I would just do this
ans = {}
for a, b, c, d in arr:
    ans.setdefault((d, a), []).append((c, b))
ans
# {('YAHOO', 2): [('JOHN K', 5), ('AARON M', 6), ('NICK C', 7)],
#  ('GOOGLE', 1): [('CELESTE G', 2), ('RICH M', 3), ('SANDEEP C', 4)]}
```

```
# Data
arr = [(2, 5, 'JOHN K', 'YAHOO'),
       (2, 6, 'AARON M', 'YAHOO'),
       (2, 7, 'NICK C', 'YAHOO'),
       (1, 2, 'CELESTE G', 'GOOGLE'),
       (1, 3, 'RICH M', 'GOOGLE'),
       (1, 4, 'SANDEEP C', 'GOOGLE')]
```

Comment: Super Pythonic solution but could you please provide comments on what each line is doing so your thought process can be understood? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much for the multiple approaches. Can we limit these to 2 persons per company? Say, Google has 3 employees in the list, then we get {('GOOGLE', 1): [('CELESTE G', 2), ('RICH M', 3)], ('GOOGLE', 1):[('SANDEEP C', 4)]} ? Thank you!

Comment: @ThinkCode. That wouldn't be possible as written as each key must be unique, and you're using the same key twice. You have to add a check for if the length of the list is >1, and either throw away the employees after the second, or make up a new subkey, like (('GOOGLE', 1), 1) and  (('GOOGLE', 1), 2).  Probably better to make the full list here and handle any subsequent data splitting per company later in your processing.

Comment: Thank you, yeah I am handling based on length. Was wondering if there is a pythonic solution for that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using groupby with the full key you want as a tuple, and putting the matches into a list of tuples, instead of a semicolon-delimited string.

```
import itertools
import operator


def accumulate(rows):
    # use lambda function to build a groupby tuple from pieces (3,0)
    it = itertools.groupby(rows, lambda x: (x[3], x[0]))
    k = {}
    for key, subiter in it:
        # for the specified key, use list comprehension to create tuples of desired elements from each row in the group.
        k[key] = [(item[2], item[1]) for item in subiter]
    return k


if __name__ == "__main__":

    rows = [
        (2, 5, "JOHN K", "YAHOO"),
        (2, 6, "AARON M", "YAHOO"),
        (2, 7, "NICK C", "YAHOO"),
        (1, 2, "CELESTE G", "GOOGLE"),
        (1, 3, "RICH M", "GOOGLE"),
        (1, 4, "SANDEEP C", "GOOGLE"),
    ]
    groupedby = accumulate(rows)

    print(groupedby)
```

output:

```
{
 ('YAHOO', 2): [('JOHN K', 5), ('AARON M', 6), ('NICK C', 7)],
 ('GOOGLE', 1): [('CELESTE G', 2), ('RICH M', 3), ('SANDEEP C', 4)]
}
```